# Не приходят данные в компонент ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

Есть `action`:

```
export const setCurrentFullData = (market, type, odd)=> dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_FULL_DATA_SUCCESS',
        payload: {
            market: market,
            type:type,
            odd: odd
        }
    });
};
```

И `reducer`:

```
const initialState = [];

export default function currentFullData(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_FULL_DATA_SUCCESS') {
        state.push(action.payload);
        return state;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Почему-то первый `return` не возвращает ничего, если поменять `state` на `action.payload` то возвращается объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления нескольких элементов в `reducer` нужно использовать функцию `concut`:

```
const initialState = [];

export default function currentFullData(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_FULL_DATA_SUCCESS') {
        let newBet = state.concat([action.payload]);
        return newBet;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо 
`state.push(action.payload)` нужно написать
`return [...state, action.payload]`
Состояние в редакс нельзя модифицировать, нужно возвращать всегда новый объект.